# Matlab. User input matrix to a string

Tags: string, matlab, user-interface, matrix

```
prompt = 'Enter ASCII codes';
dlg_title = 'Input';
num_lines = 5;
defaultans = {''};
answer = inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines,defaultans);

answer = answer{1};

m2=matrixA.'; result=char(m2(:)).'; 

result
```

What Im trying to do is write a script that when i run it, it will convert the matrix of numbers you input into a sentence. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your input matrix is a string, not numeric. Change line 7 to:

```
answer = str2num(answer{1});
```

But since you never assign anything to `matrixA`, you might as well change it to this:

```
matrixA = str2num(answer{1});
```

Comment: Plus, in your abbreviated code, you don't actually assign anything to `matrixA`. You should probably do something about that.

Comment: Undefined function or variable 'matrixA'.

Error in untitled (line 9)
m2=matrixA.'; result=char(m2(:)).';